# An contradictory negative edge

Tags: correlation, anova, spss, biostatistics, psychology

Recently I have conducted a experiment exploring the relationship between stress and mind wandering (MW). When I analyzed the data via SPSS, I found an unexpected negative edge between two variables.
My experiment was within-subject design, so every participant (26) experienced two sessioins (T:stress induction; C:control). The general procedure was that participants would receive an emotion assessment (measuring positive/negative emotion) after the stress indcution/control session, then they would complete an MW-related task during which their content of MW (e.g., Is your thought related to future?) was measured.
Here's the problem. When I performed rANOVA, I found that the positive emotion scores and future scores were lower during the stress induction session compared to control session. Therefore I suspected that stress might influence the future scores via positive emotion.  I tried to correlate the two differences of positive emotion scores and future scores to prove my hypothesis, e.g., positive scores (T-C) and future scores (T-C). Unfortunately, it showed a strong negative correlation (r = 0.47, p = 0.02).
My quesiton is: Is this strong negative edge spurious? Is my way (correlation analysis) to prove the hypothesis reasonalbe? And is there any other method I can use to find the real relationship between these two variables? [image]

Comment: I'm a little unclear, but it sounds like you are interested in a mediation model.  Can you look into those and see if I am right?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Although I couldn't find the evidence to support the foregoing hypothesis, I've found the relationships between stress and other types of MW content mediated by negative emotion. Maybe the negative correlation betweeen psotive eomtion and future scores is false.